# USB Keyboard with Sun Ray Client 3 Plus

Tags: usb-keyboard

I have two Sun Ray Client 3 plus and want to configure to be able to connect to Sun Ray Server. This Sun Ray Client using only USB port for both Mouse and Keyboard. However, after i plugged USB Keyboard and mouse into the Sun Ray Client, it seems that, the Sun Ray Client cannot find the keyboard (there is no affection when i click on keys or click on mouse buttons). Because i need to configure connection information, so one of the option is click on Ctrl + Pause + M keys but the Sun Ray does not recognize the keyboard. In window, it should take time at first to install driver for keyboard and mouse, how about Sun Ray Client?

I wonder if there is any solution for this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The SunRay thin clients need certain compliant USB keyboards and mice. You can contact Oracle/Sun about official replacement hardware, or find something on the net. You do have to find gear that is specifically compatible with SunRay however, the BIOS in the device is looking for certain hardware IDs in order to recognize the devices.

SunRay Clients are nothing like a Windows PC, I wouldn't compare them at all.